# Gradle 4.7 targetCompatibility for JDK 10

Tags: java, gradle

Anybody know what targetCompatibility value to use for JDK 10? Supposedly Gradle 4.7 supports it.

e: Currently using `1.10` but I can't find any confirmation that this is correct. `java --version` reports `10.x` instead of the usual `1.x.x` format.

Comment: See https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8180865. Assuming those values are just passed through to `javac` `-source` / `-target` flags, you should be able to use either `1.10` or `10`

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Kinda wonky honestly.

Answer (score 17):

Set the Gradle version & Java Version in build.gradle as below

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
         gradleVersion = '4.7'
     }

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
```

Now, right click the build.gradle->Gradle->Refresh Gradle Project.
And check the JRE System Library (Package Explorer view) contains JavaSE-10

Note: I am using Eclipse Oxygen IDE with Gradle IDE plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by [Phil.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)

> See [bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8180865.](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8180865) Assuming those values are just passed through to javac -source / -target flags, **you should be able to use either 1.10 or 10**